# Is there a CD containing some of the melodies of Yom Kippur?

Tags: product-recommendation, song-poetry, yom-kippur, rosh-hashanah-new-year

I'm looking for a specific piyut we say on Yom Kippur as an audio file, as I'd really like to write music for it. The prayer is in the repetition of the amidah of both Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur Shachris and Mussaf. It starts with:

> ובכן לך הכל יכתירו
>
> לאל עורך דין
>
> לבוחן לבבות ביום דין
>
> לגולה עמוקות בדין

It repeats, with each first part ending in `ביום דין` and each second part ending in `בדין`. (If you have an all-Hebrew Artscroll Machzor "Aharon Yaakov Hashalem", it's on page 241.)

There was an incredible melody which went with it and I'm totally drawing a blank on it. Does anyone know of any kosher recordings of this piyut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all such questions relating to Jewish liturgy, I highly recommend [piyut.org.il](http://www.piyut.org.il/english/). The particular tune you have in mind is probably the one [here](http://www.piyut.org.il/tradition/english/1781.html?section=morePerformances&currPerformance=2320&playing=0) (they have a few variants as well). Many would consider it the most haunting melody in the High Holy Days' services.

Comment: That wasn't the melody exactly, but thanks for the link. That helps a lot.

Comment: I think the one at that link is the "traditional" Ashkenaz melody. There is another similar, but somewhat more complex melody, that is used in many yeshivas. I don't know how widespread it is, or from where it originated.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mostlymusic.com/rosh-hashana-yom-kippur.html
Here is a whole selection of them with playable demos of each yet I am not sure this will help you as certain Baal Teffilos just use random songs as part of their repertoire and it wont be on these CD's